# Rx: Join by matching IDs

Tags: rx-java, rx.net

Let's assume there are two observables `o1, o2`. The first one receives events from an internal process (after a very long computation finished) and the second one receives external events via a REST endpoint (signaling that another, external component also finished). The event data is simply an ID.

Now I want to design a workflow so that only when an ID is present in both observables, a new event gets emitted (i.e. when the internal and external computation finished).

Let at one point in time `o1` contain the IDs `{1,2,3}`, then I want to differentiate between these cases:

1. **Normal case:** E.g. ID `2` arrives in `o2`. Both IDs are now present in both observables, output *"Success: 2"*
2. **Expire case**: Some time after the internal computation finished, the external event didn't yet arrived. E.g. ID `2` is present in `o1` but not in `o2` even after one hour, output: *"Expired: 2"*
3. **Unknown case**: An ID, e.g. 4, arrives in `o2` via the REST endpoint that is not present in `o1`, maybe because the ID already expired or simply because of a faulty external component, output: *"Unknown: 3"*

I found the `groupJoin` operator which could probably do what I want, here is even an example of attribute matching: [GroupJoin - Joins two streams matching by one of their attributes](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc39)

However, it seems as this example performs an exhausting (linear time) scan over all elements each time a new event arrives. I think it  would be possible to roll my own version that checks a map in constant time instead but: *I'm wondering if there is a canonical way or even an out-of-the-box feature for this (because I guess this is a pretty common use case).*

(And as I'm new to Rx, what is the best way to implement the expiration case for such a join operation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged the question rx.net as well, so I'll assume the luxury of giving an answer in C#. I'm not sure how well this translates to Java, if that's what you're looking for.

Rx's `Join` and `GroupJoin` aren't really meant for this: They are meant to join based on time-windows. You're looking to join by an ID.

An Rx-friendly solution would be functional. And since you need some state, so we can use an immutable state baked into a `Scan` function. In C#, there's `ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TItem>` from Nuget package `System.Collections.Immutable`. I'm not sure there's an equivalent in Java.

Given these classes:

```
public class CustomEvent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public ResultType Type { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public enum ResultType
{
    Success,
    Unknown,
    Expired
}
```

You can get a solution like this:

```
IObservable<CustomEvent> o1;
IObservable<int> o2;
TimeSpan expirationTimeDelay = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

IObservable<Result> results = Observable.Merge(
    o1.SelectMany(ce => Observable.Merge(
        Observable.Return(new Func<ImmutableDictionary<int, CustomEvent>, Tuple<ImmutableDictionary<int, CustomEvent>, Result, bool>>(h => 
            Tuple.Create(h.Add(ce.Id, ce), default(Result), false)
        )),
        Observable.Return(new Func<ImmutableDictionary<int, CustomEvent>, Tuple<ImmutableDictionary<int, CustomEvent>, Result, bool>>(h =>
            h.ContainsKey(ce.Id)
                ? Tuple.Create(h.Remove(ce.Id), new Result { Type = ResultType.Expired, Id = ce.Id}, true)
                : Tuple.Create(h, default(Result), false)
        ))
            .Delay(expirationTimeDelay)
    )),
    o2.Select(id => new Func<ImmutableDictionary<int, CustomEvent>, Tuple<ImmutableDictionary<int, CustomEvent>, Result, bool>>(h =>
        h.ContainsKey(id)
            ? Tuple.Create(h.Remove(id), new Result { Type = ResultType.Success, Id = id }, true)
            : Tuple.Create(h, new Result { Type = ResultType.Unknown, Id = id }, true)
    ))
)
.Scan(Tuple.Create(ImmutableDictionary<int, CustomEvent>.Empty, default(Result), false), (t, f) => f(t.Item1))
.Where(t => t.Item3)
.Select(t => t.Item2);
```

The immutable dictionary is our core state and holds 'live' events from `o1`. The accumulator function returns a tuple with three properties: the immutable dictionary representing our core state, a results object, and a Boolean. The Boolean object is a filter showing whether or not the results object should be propagated.

A fun trick with `Scan` is to invert the normal usage: Turn the stream of items into functions that work off the state. In our case, the type of the function is Func, Tuple, Results, Boolean>> (a function that takes in a dictionary, and returns a tuple with the three values).

That's what we do here: Each `o1` item pops out two functions: One that adds the item to the immutable dictionary (and no result pushed). Another function comes out an hour later to see if the event hasn't been joined yet. If joined, then nothing happens. If not joined, the Expired result pops out. Each `o2` item pops out a single function: Checking to see if the item is in the map. If present, Normal result pops out. If not present, then Unknown.

If you are in Java, and there's no easily available equivalent to `ImmutableDictionary`, then you can probably substitute a regular `HashMap`, but you'll have to guard it against nasty state problems from multiple subscribers with a `Publish` call.

Comment: This seems to solve my issue best. As I probably will implement it in Scala immutable data structures are no problem. If I got it correctly, this should work in constant time! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this by having the intermediate state in an external object:

```
public class ItemJoinCache<T> {
   private Map<Integer, T> items;
   public Observable<T> ingestInternal(T item) {
      // an internal item arrived, do the necessary work
   }
   public Observable<T> ingestExternal(T item) {
      // an external item arrived, do the necessary work
   }
}

externalRestCallThatReturnsObservable()
.flatMap(myItemJoinCache::ingestExternal)
...

internalProcessThatTakesALongTime()
.flatMap(myItemJoinCache::ingestInternal)
...
```

This way you can do whatever kind of processing that you might need.

Comment: Thanks, this comes pretty close to what I expected somehow. However, I accepted the other answer as it is more complete. But anyway, this a good starting point!

Comment: No problem, that's the proper behavior in SO. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can always reduce o1 to a Set with `scan`. When o2 emits a value you take the latest set from o1 with `withLatestFrom` and check inclusion. A `timeout` can solve the expiration part. Example in RxJs 5:

```
o2
.withLatestFrom(
  o1.scan((set, val) => set.add(val), new Set),
  (o2Val, o1Set) => o1Set.has(o2Val) ? "Success" : "Unknown"
)
.timeoutWith(3600000, Observable.of("Expire"))
.subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Looks good but I wonder if this works in constant time. I assume that "scan" would lead to a linear time run time.

Comment: Yes, in fact you're building a Set of elements coming from o1 and that takes linear time. The point is your real computation happens when an element comes from o2, then the last available Set is taken from o1 in constant time. This solution is efficient and much simpler than the other.